# How to enable display of framebuffer images (e.g. in w3m, fbi) within byobu (pts)?

Tags: command-line, byobu, framebuffer, w3m

I'm trying to run a minimal Ubuntu 13.10 installation *without X Window System* on my old laptop. One of the most useful tools I rely on in this setup is `byobu`; however, it seems to prevent me from using applications capable of displaying images in framebuffer.

One such program is the browser `w3m` (installed with its `w3m-img` package). Executed from outside `byobu` (in `tty1`), though only if preceded by `sudo`, it displays web pages with images loaded as expected. However, if `byobu` is enabled (and thus my terminal is no longer identified as `tty1`, but rather as `dev/pts/1`), there's no way to get `w3m` to display images (no matter if I launch it with `sudo` or not).

The same applies to the `fbi` image viewer. Outside of `byobu` (but again, only if I launch it with `sudo`), it works without any problems. With `byobu` enabled, it instead produces an error message, the relevant bit of which seems to be

```
ioctl VT_GETSTATE: Inappropriate ioctl for device (not a linux console?)
```

As far as I understand, it all has to do something with the fact that `byobu` relies on a pseudo-terminal, and with some arcane permission settings (as the `sudo` requirement I mentioned seems to indicate).

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: Have you tried adding yourself to the video group?

Comment: I have same issue. When I'm disable byobu I can view images with framebuffer via w3m command, but fbi still not working.

Answer (score 4):

As [Braden Best's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/411721) says, you need to add your user to the `video` group.

But you can also do it with the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G video {your username}
```

Log out and back in (or reboot) after doing this to see the change.

Answer (score 1):

The framebuffer device (`/dev/fb0`) is owned by user `root` and group `video`

```
$ ls -l /dev/fb0
crw-rw---- 1 root video 29, 0 Jan 27 11:00 /dev/fb0
```

To avoid using `sudo` to make programs using the framebuffer work, you would add yourself to the `video` group.

First, edit the file. I'm using vim for this example, and assuming no prior knowledge of how to use it.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/group
```

While in vim, find the video line. To do that, just type `/video` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then, add yourself to the group by typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by your username, and then save the file by typing <kbd>esc</kbd> followed by `:wq`, and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

A quick restart of your shell, and you should be able to use programs like `fbi` without prefixing it with `sudo`

Comment: I know there's a command for doing this, but I can never remember it, haha.